# Migrating menu tree code from jquery 1.7.1 to 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, submenu

I've a js code working with jquery 1.7.1 broken after migration to 1.9.1
You can see the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/QK5Ld/2/.

The code I'm using is this:

```
$("#navigation li ul").each(function(){
    var that = this;
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).prev().toggle(function() { 
                              $(that).show(); 
                          }, 
                          function() { 
                              $(that).hide(); 
                          }
                     );
})
```

I read that toggle() is no more supported but I'm no js expert and I've lost many hours trying to complete update this js code.

Any idea?
Thank you in advance.

Nicola.

Note: The HTML used is like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li id="category-2850">
         <a href="/category/archiviazione/">ARCHIVIAZIONE</a>
         <ul>
            <li id="category-3021">
               <a href="/category/archiviazione/archiviazione-modulare/">ARCHIVIAZIONE MODULARE</a>
               <ul>
                  <li id="category-3326"><a href="/category/archiviazione/archiviazione-modulare/scatole-archivio-con-maniglie/">SCATOLE ARCHIVIO CON MANIGLIE</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3022"><a href="/category/archiviazione/archiviazione-modulare/scatole-archivio-in-cartone/">SCATOLE ARCHIVIO IN CARTONE</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="category-2876">
               <a href="/category/archiviazione/buste-trasparenti/">BUSTE TRASPARENTI</a>
               <ul>
                  <li id="category-2917"><a href="/category/archiviazione/buste-trasparenti/buste-a-perforazione-universale/">BUSTE A PERFORAZIONE UNIVERSALE</a></li>
                  <li id="category-2916"><a href="/category/archiviazione/buste-trasparenti/buste-a-u/">BUSTE A U</a></li>
                  <li id="category-2877"><a href="/category/archiviazione/buste-trasparenti/buste-per-usi-diversi-e-dedicati/">BUSTE PER USI DIVERSI E DEDICATI</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="category-3100">
         <a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/">ARREDAMENTO E COMPLEMENTI</a>
         <ul>
            <li id="category-3101">
               <a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/">COMPLEMENTI D'ARREDO</a>
               <ul>
                  <li id="category-3102"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/accessori-vari/">ACCESSORI VARI</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3215"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/appendiabiti/">APPENDIABITI</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3307"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/cestini-e-posacenere/">CESTINI E POSACENERE</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3189"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/lampade-da-tavolo/">LAMPADE DA TAVOLO</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3214"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/lampade-da-terra/">LAMPADE DA TERRA</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3217"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/orologi-barometri-da-scrivania-e-da-parete/">OROLOGI - BAROMETRI DA SCRIVANIA E DA PARETE</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3336"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/piante-sintetiche-e-vasi/">PIANTE SINTETICHE E VASI</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3216"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/portaombrelli/">PORTAOMBRELLI</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3173"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/tappeti-e-zerbini/">TAPPETI E ZERBINI</a></li>
                  <li id="category-3328"><a href="/category/arredamento-e-complementi/complementi-d-arredo/tavolini-e-sedie-zona-ristoro/">TAVOLINI E SEDIE ZONA RISTORO</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding the jQuery Migrate plugin (http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin) and see what the console says.

Comment: For a short-term fix, you could use the jquery-migrate library, which brings back all the deprecated functionality that was removed in jquery 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code actually becomes cleaner in 1.9:

```
$("#navigation li ul").each(function(){
    var that = this;
    $(this).hide().prev().click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(that).toggle();
    });
});
```

Though this would have worked just as well in previous versions too.

Update: here's an even better way:

```
$("#navigation li ul").hide().prev().click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QK5Ld/6/)

Comment: I wonder why was the `href` of the anchor not being followed in his fiddle if he didn't used `preventDefault` or anything. On your works but the link is followed.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL From the docs on `.toggle`: `The implementation also calls .preventDefault() on the event, so links will not be followed and buttons will not be clicked if .toggle() has been called on the element.`

Comment: @ColinDeClue Thanks. Thanks to you I've searched and noted there are two pages for `toggle`, depending if you use as [animation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

Comment: Note however one of the two has been removed in 1.9

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly, thank you!
Now I'm wondering if it is possible to close other trees when you click on a new node.